# Can't add foreign key in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, api

I am making an API using django without restframework.
I have problem on adding data via POST request. All the data are added except *Foreign Key which is **contact numbers*** it can add one or more contact numbers

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def phonebook_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        phonebooklist = PhoneBook.objects.all()
        serialized_data = [pb.to_json() for pb in phonebooklist]
        return JsonResponse(serialized_data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
            data= request.body.decode('utf8')
            data= json.loads(data)
            try:
                new_contact=PhoneBook(name=data["name"],
                address=data["address"],
                email=data["email"],
                note=data["note"])
                new_contact.save()

                new_contact_number=ContactNumber(
                contact_number=data["contact_number"], #No Contact Numbers Added # It should add one or more contact numbers
                number_id=data[PhoneBook.id] #It should add the contact number/s to the contact name added together
                )
                contact_number.save()

                return JsonResponse({"created": data}, safe= False)
            except:
                return JsonResponse({"error":"not valid data"}, safe=False)
```

**models.py**

```
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='address')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='email')
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='note')

    def to_json(self):

        contact_numbers = [c.contact_number
                     for c in self.contact_numbers.all()]
        return { 
            'name':            self.name, 
            'email':           self.email, 
            'address':         self.address,
            'note':            self.note,
            'contact_numbers': contact_numbers
         }

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name

class ContactNumber(models.Model):  
    number = models.ForeignKey(PhoneBook, related_name="contact_numbers")
    contact_number= models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.contact_number
```

**This is the result in postman after I added some data**
The first one is the correct data, second is the wrong one I entered
[Image result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne9kJ.png)

Database table:
contactnumber table:
http://prntscr.com/jofv8h
phonebook table:
http://prntscr.com/jofvt6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer,

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def phonebook_list(request):
    #your code
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.body.decode('utf8')
        data = json.loads(data)
        try:
            new_contact = PhoneBook.objects.create(name=data["name"],address=data["address"],email=data["email"],note=data["note"])
            ContactNumber.objects.create(contact_number=data["contact_number"],number=new_contact)
            serialized_data = [new_contact.to_json()]
            return JsonResponse({"created": serialized_data}, safe=False)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"error": "not valid data"}, safe=False)
```

**UPDATE-1**
change your view as below,

```
def phonebook_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        phonebooklist = PhoneBook.objects.all()
        serialized_data = [pb.to_json() for pb in phonebooklist]
        return JsonResponse(serialized_data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.body.decode('utf8')
        data = json.loads(data)

        try:
            new_contact = PhoneBook.objects.create(name=data["name"], address=data["address"], email=data["email"], note=data["note"])
            for number in data["contact_numbers"]:
                ContactNumber.objects.create(contact_number=number, number=new_contact)
            serialized_data = [new_contact.to_json()]
            return JsonResponse({"created": serialized_data}, safe=False)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"error": "not valid data"}, safe=False)
```

Then the `POST payload` will be like this,

```
{
        "name": "George",
        "email": "zxc1@gmail.com",
        "address": "address-32",
        "note": "note-77",
        "contact_numbers": [
            "11",
            "22",
            "33",
            "44"
        ]
    }
```

By this format, you can add `n` number of `phone number` at a time.
The view response be like

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jerin",
        "email": "email1@gmail.com",
        "address": "address-1",
        "note": "note-1",
        "contact_numbers": [
            "123654",
            "136285452"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Peter",
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "address": "address-2",
        "note": "note11",
        "contact_numbers": [
            "789654"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "George",
        "email": "zxc1@gmail.com",
        "address": "address-32",
        "note": "note-77",
        "contact_numbers": [
            "11",
            "22",
            "33",
            "44"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: still the contact numbers are blank, I put print below the line of **ContactNumber.objects.create** but it is no response, so maybe there is wrong on creating object on ContactNumber.

Comment: its working now, I forgot to add letter `s` on the contact_number=data["contact_number**s**"] . Thank you so much.

Comment: But I am getting wrong format on the contact numbers. It's weird, look at the contact_number list [Image here](http://prntscr.com/joj74f) `{ "name": "Alvin", "email": "qwe@gmail.com", "address": "Col", "note": "noting", "contact_number": [ "['123456', '1234567']" ] }`

Comment: But when I manually adding to the admin page, no problem at all

Comment: Oh oh... I couldn't understand what the problem is.. C

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605743/django-json-format-error

Comment: It's ok now, I looped the contact numbers if contactnumber is greater than 1.

`contact_number = data['contact_number']
  for x in contact_number:
    qs = ContactNumber(qs.number_id = new_contact.id, qs.contact_number = x)
    qs.save()`

Comment: check **UPDATE-1** section

Comment: Yehey, its working now. Thank you so much! I appreciate your update, it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to learn how to save an ForeignKey in Django, this example will help you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

and you can learn how django deal with default id in your model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

In your case, ForeignKey column is `number`, save the new contract object you just created, not save the id

```
new_contact_number=ContactNumber(
                    contact_number=data["contact_number"],
                    number=new_contact)
new_contact_number.save()
```

Comment: it is should only contact number in object? or the contact.id? as shown in the database table I presented above.

Comment: @ajiejot django will help you autocreate contact.id, so you not need to care about it, except you need to set your special id column

Comment: its working now, I forgot to add letter `s` on the contact_number=data["contact_number**s**"] . Thank you so much. But I use to add the newly id of newly created contact.